# Induced map of quotient modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose that $R$ is a ring, $I \subset R$ is an ideal, and $f : A \to B$ is a homomorphism of $R$-modules.  Is it true that there is an induced homomorphism $f/I : A/IA \to B/IB$ which is a map of $R/I$-modules?

I realize this should be easy to check (or dis-check), but I'm having a hard time figuring out what exactly needs to be verified.  I know $f(x+iy) = f(x) + i f(y)$ which is the same thing in $B/IB$, so I get a map of $R$-modules at least.  What does it mean to be a map of $R/I$-modules?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.
$$f : A \to B$$ now tensor with $R/I$: $$f\otimes_R1_{R/I}:A\otimes_R R/I \to B\otimes_R R/I $$ and use $A\otimes_R R/I \equiv A/IA$.
(this even shows that if $f$ is surjective then $f/I$ is surjective too)

Comment: Has OP covered tensors yet?

Comment: If I understand right, this gets me a map of $R$-modules.  Is it a map of $R/I$ modules?

Comment: it is a map of R/I modules